# Cocos2dx - Clearing specific textures from the cache

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am getting crashes on iPhone 4s due to "memory pressure." My game is set up like this:

1. Main scene sprite sheet that always stays in memory.
2. Individual game scene levels load from individual textures (not sprite sheets).

When a level is done and we return to the main scene, I would like those cached game scene textures to get dumped. What ends up happening is that when you play through 3-4 levels, it crashes as it runs out of memory as it never releases this memory after a level. I don't want the level textures to be cached past the lifespan of the game scene. When returning to the main scene, it needs to release this memory.

I have tried removing all of the game scene children which does nothing to memory. I have tried looking for a specific way to clear just these textures I have loaded in this game scene from the cache.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using cocos2d v2? You probably have memory leaks since unused textures are removed when necessary. Try profiling your app to see if you have leaks and where they are at.

You also can call these methods yourself at the appropriate time, although I doubt you'd have to:

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
```

But again what you describe sounds more like memory leaks. When your application receives a memory warning the cached data is purged. During this purge the remove unused textures method is called on the texture cache, among other things. If you have 3/4 levels of data still lurking around long after you've exited those scenes, that sounds like a memory leak.

I'm assuming this only happens after visiting multiple scenes and the problem just isn't that your 4th scene is simply trying to load more data than the device can handle.

Comment: I have debugged and fixed two memory leaks neither of which were texture related and both were about 16 bytes total. Still at a loss.

Comment: Are you removing things like observers? How much memory is being used by the time you get to the 3rd level?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove specific textures calling:

In cocos2D-x v3.x :

```
Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->removeTextureForKey(ImageKeyName)
```

In cocos2D-x v2.x :

```
CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->removeTextureForKey(ImageKeyName);
```

Where ImageKeyName is just the path of the image (the same you used to load the texture)